# Ошибка при вводе: The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, denwer

Почему при вводе этого - http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ выходит 
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
Подсказка Денвера

Вы ошиблись при наборе URL в браузере. Вероятнее всего, сервер пытается найти файл Z:/home/localhost/www/phpmyadmin/, которого не существует.

В случае использования CGI-скриптов, корректные пути к CGI-директориям следующие:
Denwer запущен

Comment: видимо потому, что phpMyAdmin не установлен или он доспупен по другому адресу.

Comment: А ты проверь, есть ли он там вообще? 

>> Z:/home/localhost/www

Если есть, то следующим пунктом нужно проверять конфиги веб-сервера (скорее всего, в них и беда), в частности .htaccess. Если и там все норм, то я бы посмотрел еще hosts, указан ли соответствующий алиас.

>> c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\

Answer (score 1):

Наверное потому что писать нужно http://localhost/pma/

Comment: Все равно одно и тоже выходит

Comment: почему pma?

Comment: А сможете написать последовательность действий,ото я не очень разбираюсь

Comment: pma указывается потому что в последних мануалах по установке phpmyadmin настраивается быстрый доступ к базе данных именно через pma (Мануал: http://php-myadmin.ru/learning/instrument-pma.html)

если это не работает, значит ошибка в установке окружения. Может просто апач (денвер) не запущен, может адрес на PhpMuAdmin прописан не верно, или еще что, это может быть уже что угодно.

Comment: ясно, русским не пользовался сайтом никогда, а на официальном такого нет :)